# My app-routing setup gives 404 on refresh

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I am developing an angular application with deep linking and i keep getting a 404 on refresh.
Regularly, I do this

```
{ path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }
```

but in my situation, I am doing this:

```
{
path: 'dashboard',
component: LayoutComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    outlet: 'center'
  },
  {
    path: 'detail/new',
    component: DetailComponent,
    outlet: 'center'
  },
  {
    path: 'detail/edit/:id',
    component: DetailComponent,
    outlet: 'center'
  },
  {
    path: 'detail/view/:id',
    component: DetailComponent,
    outlet: 'center'
  },

]
}
```

so that when I go to '/dashboard/detail/new' I go to the corresponding page and so on.
this works the first time, but when I refresh, it gives a 404 when trying to load the js files (polyfill, main, etc). What could be the issue?

For my router module, this is what i have

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'});
```

I looked for solutions here, but the solution was to use hash, and that is not the solution for me, because it goes to the first page we started out from, and this is bad for user experience.
Not sure what else I could try

Comment: Is your application deployed or is this happening when serving from localhost?

Comment: how is your empty path defined?

Comment: @jamesmallred its localhost

Comment: @micronyks its redirecting to home

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: @jamesmallred I'm getting a 404 in the network when it tries to load the js files (polyfill, runtime, main)

Comment: _"the solution was to use hash, and that is not the solution for me, because it goes to the first page we started out from"_ - no, this isn't how Angular's router with `useHash` works. Have you tried it?

Comment: @mbojko I did try it, it added the hash and then redirected to the home page

Comment: how many named router outlets do you have in your template? If all you have is center, try removing the named router outlets.

Comment: @jamesmallred I have 3 in total, so removing it doesn't show the screen

Comment: You can leave just the one <router-outlet> in the template and the named outlets in the routing module. It's unnecessary unless you have routes pointing to the same path that need to load different components in the outlet. What I would do is take the dashboard component and routing module back to the bare minimum and troubleshoot from there. Without full access, this kind of difficult to resolve.

Comment: You might want to create separate components for Edit and View within the DashboardComponent as well.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of angular you are using now?
if it is angular ivy(9 or 10) then change your route like this:

```
{
    path: 'detail',
    children: [
      { path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('./detail.module').then(m => DetailPageModule)
      },
      { path: 'edit/:id',
        loadChildren: () => import('./detail/edit.module').then(m => m.EditPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'new',
        loadChildren: () => import('./detail/new.module').then(m => m.NewPageModule)
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: They are components, not modules. The paradigm you are referencing is for lazy loading feature modules. https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules